# Installing PHP 5.4 on RHEL5, getting caught in dependency rabbit-hole

Tags: php, installation, yum, rhel5

I tried using webstatic, epel and remi repo's and all fail with the following error:

```
Missing Dependency: openldap >= 2.3.43-25.el5_8.1 is 
needed by package libcurl-7.27.0-10.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
```

Fine, OK, openldap version on my system is:

```
sudo yum list package openldap
Installed Packages
openldap.i386            2.3.43-3.el5         installed    
openldap.x86_64          2.3.43-3.el5         installed
```

(What's sad is i'm only off by a patch release -3 to -25! grr!)

Let's install OPENLDAP 2.4 from rpm since it's not available on any of the repo's:

```
wget http://someurl/downloads/openldap-2.4.24.tgz
tar -zxf openldap-2.4.24.tgz
cd openldap-2.4.24
./configure
```

Get this error:

```
checking if Berkeley DB version supported by BDB/HDB backends... no
configure: error: BerkeleyDB version incompatible with BDB/HDB backends
```

I just want to upgrade PHP 5.1 to 5.4 on RedHat Linux 5 86_x64. It doesn't have to be this freakin' complicated! Anybody have any ideas?

Compiling php from source is a dependency nightmare! but I attempted it anyway:

```
sudo rpm -ivh php54-5.4.16-1.ius.el5.src.rpm
Password:
warning: php54-5.4.16-1.ius.el5.src.rpm: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 9cd4953f
   1:php54                  warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root x8
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root x8
########################################### [100%]
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
...repeated 8 more times.
```

i apparantly finished 100% but there's no sign of it under `sudo rpm -qa | grep *php*` returns zero results. (FYI: I have already 'yum removed' php 5.1 already)

Thanks for any help

Comment: did you not try and install openldap from rpm? http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/5.9/x86_64/CentOS/openldap-2.3.43-25.el5_8.1.x86_64.html

Comment: Yeah I did, for brevity I didn't mention it. I got the same error as with yum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working through brute force. I downloaded all the RPMS for php I needed (cli,devel,common,pdo,mysql,xml,ldap).

I compiled openldap 2.3.5 from source and yum installed 'libedit' (one of the php rpms needed it

Then i ran rpm -ivh on each of the php rpm's. Some depended on each other so there's definitely an order to do them in (example pdo must go before mysql), but by trial and error PHP 5.4 is successfully installed.

Something that should have been as simple as

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://some.complete.repo/
sudo yum install php php-common php-cli php-devel php-xml php-pdo php-mysql php-ldap
```

But welcome to the world of Linux :P. (And one wonders how Microsoft did well over all these years with their crappy OS)

/end_rant

Answer (score -1):

It's much easier to install epel and remi repositories and then do a yum install:
http://kb.parallels.com/en/115833